# How to Refresh a Tab in Tkinter after Interacting with a Database?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a python script for teachers that works very well on my terminal and I'm trying to use Tkinter so I can share this script with other people.  In the script, the user uploads a file and other information to an SQLite database.

Below is part of the script that shows just the content for the 1st tab (of 3). The problem is that when people interact with the database the tab needs to get refreshed to show something has happened and that the list of files in the database has changed.

Everything I've read shows you need a button to refresh.  But that is not user-friendly. What people want to do is upload a file and then see that file in the list. Is this possible with Tkinter and if so how?

```
class AppWindow():
    my_list = [4]

    def __init__(self, parent):
        global my_list

        # Create the window
        self.window = parent
        self.window.geometry("700x600")
        #self.center_window()
        self.window.title("Test app")
        # Create a text label and place it in the window
        self.hello_label = tk.Label(self.window, text="Hello world!")
        self.hello_label.place(x=20, y=20)
        # Create 3 tabs
        self.tab_container = tk.Frame(self.window)
        self.tab_container.place(x=0,y=0,width=700,height=400)
        self.tabs = ttk.Notebook(self.tab_container)
        self.tab_2 = tk.Frame(self.tabs)
        self.tabs.add(self.tab_2, text="Parameters")
        self.tabs.place(x=0,y=0,height=400,width=700)
        # Content for tab 2
        self.label2 = tk.Label(self.tab_2, text="")
        self.label201=tk.Label(self.tab_2, text="Put in your target GPA")
        self.label201.place(x=50, y=50)
        btn1 = tk.Button(self.tab_2,text="Target GPA", command=self.getGPA)
        btn1.place(x=50, y=80)
        for lst in self.my_list:
            btn99=tk.Button(self.tab_2,text=lst)
            btn99.grid()

    def getGPA(self):
        userInput = sd.askstring('User Input','Enter target GPA')
        self.my_list.append(userInput)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = AppWindow(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You need to provide a [mre] which means taking out all the stuff unrelated to your question, like reading from a SQL database and reading Excel file with pandas. The reason is because leaving them in **dramatically** reduces the number of folks how can run your code and test their answers before posting them.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean...I took out everything unrelated to my question.  To see how this works you need to see the function that uploads the data (UploadAction), the tabs (I took out all the unrelated tabs and only showed one tab) and I have to show the function that lists the data.  If I take all of these out, then nobody can understand the problem.

Comment: Sure, that makes sense. I can try to change the entire program to avoid a database but without the database part the problem disappears since nobody will be uploading any information

Comment: You will simply have to create something that simulates reading the database and changing the tab.

Comment: `sd.askstring()` is undefined in your updated code, so it's not runnable. It's also unclear how the scenario you describe maps onto the current code — i.e. what's equivalent to interacting with the database (or maybe uploading a file) causing the tab to need to be refreshed? In other words how does it reproduce the problem?

Comment: Do you mean that there will be more than one teacher execute the script at the same time in different machines?

Comment: no, each teacher would have their own program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is merely a guess because of the all the reasons I've already mentioned in comments under your question. Generally speaking, to update or what you call "refresh" a tab requires adding, changing, or deleting the widgets you put on it.

The code below is based what's currently in your code. Every time the <kbd>Target GP</kbd> button is clicked another `Button` is added to the `self.tab_2` frame as well as appended to `my_list`. Changing the widgets doesn't have to be triggered by clicking on a button, it could be the result of some other event (such as the completion of a file upload in the background for example).

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
import tkinter.simpledialog as sd


class AppWindow():
    def __init__(self, parent):
        # Create the window
        self.window = parent
        self.window.geometry("700x600")
        #self.center_window()
        self.window.title("Test app")

        # Create and initialize data list.
        self.my_list = [4]

        # Create a text label and place it in the window
        self.hello_label = tk.Label(self.window, text="Hello world!")
        self.hello_label.place(x=20, y=20)

        # Create 3 tabs
        self.tab_container = tk.Frame(self.window)
        self.tab_container.place(x=0, y=0, width=700, height=400)
        self.tabs = ttk.Notebook(self.tab_container)

        self.tab_2 = tk.Frame(self.tabs)
        self.tabs.add(self.tab_2, text="Parameters")
        self.tabs.place(x=0, y=0, height=400, width=700)

        # Content for tab 2
        self.label201 = tk.Label(self.tab_2, text="Put in your target GPA")
        self.label201.place(x=50, y=50)
        btn1 = tk.Button(self.tab_2, text="Target GPA", command=self.getGPA)
        btn1.place(x=50, y=80)

        # Create a Button for each item currently in list.
        for item in self.my_list:
            btn = tk.Button(self.tab_2, text=item)
            btn.grid()

    def getGPA(self):
        userInput = sd.askstring('User Input', 'Enter target GPA')
        if userInput is None:  # User closed the dialog or clicked Cancel?
            return
        self.my_list.append(userInput)
        btn = tk.Button(self.tab_2, text=userInput)  # Create another Button.
        btn.grid()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = AppWindow(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks..I'm going to try this out.  It appears when you click the Target GPA button you are not giving the option of what GPA to put in.  I'll see if I can this working.

Comment: So, I have this working - thanks - it works for adding to the database (or list in the above script).  It doesn't appear to have a way to delete an item, however.

Comment: There's no way to input what GPA because the code in your question didn't define `sd.askstring()`, so I just hardcoded something. If you want to delete (or otherwise change) existing widgets, you will need to create your own list of them so they can be referred to later. To delete everything in a tab frame you could call the `destroy()` method of each widget in the list `self.tab_2.winfo_children()` returns thereby making use of the internal list that tkinter keeps.

Comment: Thanks Maritineau.  Yes, I forgot to put in import tkinter.simpledialog as sd for the string.  I'll use the destoy method as you suggest...again, thanks so much for helping me on this problem...really appreciate it.